# how can i fix the error "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT"?

Tags: swift, button, uibutton

[image: picture of the connection inspector]

I have created a ViewController with a view and a button. I have declared the button as an outlet and as an Action in the viewcontroller. Additionally I am passing the data of the first Viewcontroller to the second Viewcontroller with a segue. When I click the cancel button which executes a segue back to the first viewcontroller I get the error

> Thread 1: signal SIGABRT.

The error is shown in the prepare function which is passing the data. I have already controlled the connection inspector. I don't know what is wrong with my code.

here is my code:

```swift
 @IBAction func cancelButton(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "backToFirstScreen", sender: self)
    }


 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let tableViewVC = segue.destination as! tableViewController
        
        tableViewVC.passwordNotes3 = passwordNotes2
        tableViewVC.passwordCategory3 = passwordCategory2
        tableViewVC.passwordStrings3 = passwordStrings2
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is that you havent created a "backToFirstScreen" segue that starts in the second view controller and ends in the first viewcontroller.

Using a segue to go back to the first screen is slightly taboo; I would replace

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "backToFirstScreen", sender: self)
```

with

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

or if you're using a navigation controller

```
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

This allows you to dismiss the current viewcontroller youre looking at and return to the view controller which presented it without having to create a segue that goes in reverse. Just make sure you have a segue that goes from the first view controller to the second view controller in that order.

Comment: oh thanks i didnt knew that it is possible to use the dismiss method with a viewcontroller, but now its working thank you !!

Comment: No problem :) Click on the checkmark to show that this answer is correct, please.